# How to detect when composed html file is loaded in Durandal (after activator activated new item)

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0

I'm using activator and I can detect when new view model was loaded and even activated but how to detect when its html counterpart was loaded and displayed? I just need to do something shortly after old html (composed/embedded into page) was replaced with new html. Note that I'm interested in *change* of embedded html, not the initial composition.

Note 2: I need to detect this from parent view model - the one which has activator (the one which loads, not the one which *is* loaded).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`binding` event in your view model](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM/):

> When the composition engine takes your view and object, and uses the binder to bind them together, two other callbacks are executed before and after the binding takes place. binding(view) is called prior to binding and bindingComplete(view) is called immeidately after. Each call passes the view to your object.

Comment: Thanks but please see added Note 2, sorry that question was not precise enough without this note.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is not correct -

You need to use the attached callback and expose it to the requiring module.  You can do so like this -

```
function attached() {
    console.log('View has been attached');
}
```

If you wanted to fire an event here to let a subscriber such as the parent view model you could do so like this -

```
var callback;

function activate(callbackFunction) {
    callback = callbackFunction;
}
function attached() {
    callbackFunction();
}
```

Where this new view was composed with a binding passed in.

```
define(['viewmodels/otherViewModel'], function (otherViewModel) {

    function thisIsACallback () {
        alert('Called back');
    }

    // Instantiate the other view model
    function callOtherViewModel () {
        var whatever = new otherViewModel(thisIsACallback);
    }

});
```

And showed it in the view.

**EDIT**

If that isn't what you are looking for, then you can always just watch the activeInstruction or see if the router is still navigating -

```
var token = router.activeInstruction.subscribe(function() {
    // Do whatever you want here
}

var token = router.isNavigating.subscribe(function() {
    // Do whatever you want here
}
```

Just check the API Documentation for the other exposed methods

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api/#module/router/class/Router

Comment: Using callback or other code placed in each loaded view model (business focused) is something I would like to avoid. I consider it an infrastructure code and I have Durandal to not have to place infrastructure code in business code.

Comment: Then why do you care what you are loading if you want it to be stateless and not know anything about the view model you are calling?  I will add a portion to the answer that may help you but I don't think your question is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help me but I think you didn't see problem I was solving. I don't care *what* I'm loading. I just care that I *have loaded something*. This is for visual purposes only. Simply I want to hide old embedded view before I start loading new and show it after the new html is loaded. I'm not using router, just plain Activator. I did what I wanted using transition as a workaround so direct answer to my question is still welcomed.